# Standalone libraries similar to certain bootstrap components

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, libraries

I've been using Bootstrap3 for quiet some time now. I liked some perticular components of bootstrap, like pills navigation, Navigation bars, panels, wells, etc.
Now, I want standalone libraries dedicated to do each of those tasks, like a standalone library for Panels, a standalone library for Pills, etc.
Please give me examples of good quality libraries for:

1. Panels
2. Navigation Bar (which shall be fixed to top)
3. Wells
4. Pills
5. Something like Affix-Plugin